# differentiability of a map.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I am studying the differentiability of the map $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$

$$
f(x)=\int_1^{\infty}\left|\frac{sin(\pi x e^y)}{y}\right|dy.
$$

Any guess or proof of its differentiability. Is it $C^{\infty}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this integral converges. With the substitution $u= x e^y$, we have
$$
f(x)=\frac1{ x}\int_{ x e}^\infty \frac{|\sin \pi u|}{u\log u}\,du.
$$
On intervals of the form $\left[\frac{(2k-1)}2-\frac14,\frac{(2k-1)}2+\frac14\right]$, we have $|\sin\pi u|\geq\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Thus, for an appropriate $m$,
$$
\int_{xe}^\infty\frac{|\sin u|}{u\log u}\,du\geq\frac1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k=m}^\infty\int_{k-3/4}^{k-1/4}\frac{du}{u\log u}
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k=m}^\infty \log\left(\frac{4k-1}{4k-3}\right)\\
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sum_{k=m}^\infty \log\left(1+\frac2{4k-3}\right).
$$
For $k$ big, $\log\left(1+\frac2{4k-3}\right)\sim\frac{2}{4k-3}$, so the series diverges.